# Change RGtk2 hbox height

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk

I'm trying to add "next" and "previous" buttons to my RGtk2 layout.

I've put the "next" and "prev" buttons into their own Hbox and added them to the end of the GUI.

Unfortunately the Hbox containing these buttons expands to take up a 1/3 of the overall area of the screen, as can be seen below:

[image]

I'd like the new hbox to take up as little space as possible, to allow maximum room for the second graph. How can I shrink the height of the Hbox?

I've tried inserting the hbox using packEnd, rather than packStart  and it looks exactly the same.

Here's the code:

```
library(RGtk2)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(cairoDevice)


# data generation ---------------------------------------------------------

s1 = mvrnorm(1000, c(0, 0), matrix(c(1, 0.8, 0.8, 1),2,2))

s2 = mvrnorm(1000, c(0,0), matrix( c(1,-0.8,-0.8,1),2,2))

# code --------------------------------------------------------------------


window <- gtkWindow(show = FALSE)


frame_main <- gtkFrameNew("test")
window$add(frame_main)

graphics_old <- gtkDrawingArea()
graphics_new <- gtkDrawingArea()


button_next = gtkButtonNewWithLabel("Next")
button_prev = gtkButtonNewWithLabel("Previous")
button_test = gtkButtonNewWithLabel("test")
button_reset = gtkButtonNewWithLabel("Reset")

textbox_example<- gtkEntryNew() 
textbox_example$setWidthChars(100)

label = gtkLabelNewWithMnemonic("Input your text here") 




vbox_1 = gtkVBoxNew()
vbox_1$setBorderWidth(10)
vbox_1$packStart(graphics_old, expand = TRUE, fill = TRUE, padding = 0)
vbox_1$packStart(label,expand = FALSE, fill = FALSE, padding = 0)
vbox_1$packStart(textbox_example,expand = FALSE, fill = FALSE, padding = 0)
vbox_1$packStart(button_test,expand = FALSE, fill = FALSE, padding = 0)
frame_main$add(vbox_1)


vbox_2 = gtkVBoxNew()
vbox_2$packStart(graphics_new, expand = TRUE, fill = TRUE, padding = 0)
vbox_2$packStart(button_reset,expand = FALSE, fill = FALSE, padding = 0)
vbox_1$packStart(vbox_2)



vbox_3 = gtkHBoxNew()
vbox_3$packStart(button_next, expand = TRUE,fill = FALSE, padding = 0)
vbox_3$packStart(button_prev, expand = TRUE,fill = FALSE, padding = 0)
vbox_2$packStart(vbox_3)

window$setDefaultSize(1000,1000)
window$showAll()

asCairoDevice(graphics_old)
plot(s1)

asCairoDevice(graphics_new)
plot(s2)
```

Furthermore, there seem to be hardly any tutorials for RGtk on the internet. I've found one on R-Bloggers and one in some ancient stats paper. If you know where I can get more please let me know.

**EDIT: Setting expand = FALSE**

As suggested in the comments, I've set expand = FALSE. This just pushes the buttons to the left. The height of the box remains unchanged.

```
vbox_3 = gtkHBoxNew()
vbox_3$packStart(button_next, expand = FALSE,fill = FALSE, padding = 0)
vbox_3$packStart(button_prev, expand = FALSE,fill = FALSE, padding = 0)
vbox_2$packStart(vbox_3)
```

[image]

Comment: You have set the buttons to expand, try setting `expand = False`.

Comment: @theGtknerd Thanks. I've tried this but it just pushed the buttons to the left of the box. I've added a screenshot.

Comment: Is it `vbox_2$packStart(vbox_3, expand = FALSE, fill = FALSE, 0)` then?

Comment: If this worked for you, please post an answer for other people coming here. Or let me know that it worked and I can post an answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you please add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom box with the two buttons was set by default to expand. To set it to take minimal space use:

```
vbox_2$packStart(vbox_3, expand = FALSE, fill = FALSE, 0)
```